# Counting and printing zeroes and negative values for each Column in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to print a statement showing me both zero and negative value counts in each Dataframe column.

My input would be something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-3, -2, 0], 'b': [-2, 2, 5], 'c': [-1, 0, 7], 'd': [1, 4, 8]})
```

Which prints:

```
   a  b  c  d
0 -3 -2 -1  1
1 -2  2  0  4
2  0  5  7  8
```

The outputs I desire are:

```
Negatives Found:
a    2
b    1
c    1
d    0

Zeros Found:
a    1
b    0
c    1
d    0
```

I can't find an easy way to get to this without creating a Dataframe from the Dataframe using something like:

```
df_neg = df < 0
df_zero = df == 0
```

However, this only counts if True or False.

What's the best way of doing a count that is printable and 'easy' to run on bigger data sets?

Comment: I'm confused. There are no zero values in your input.

Comment: Ok, so now you've fixed that, what did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: Just use `df.lt(0).sum()` and `df.eq(0).sum()`

Comment: adding sum at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html)

`df.where(condition).count()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-3, -2, 0], 'b': [-2, 2, 5], 'c': [-1, 0, 7], 'd': [1, 4, 8]})
print('Negatives Found:')
print(df.where(df < 0).count())
print('Zeros Found:')
print(df.where(df == 0).count())
```

This prints

```
Negatives Found:
a    2
b    1
c    1
d    0

Zeros Found:
a    1
b    0
c    1
d    0
```

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat what you tried:

Negatives:

```
(df<0).sum()
```

Zeros:

```
(df==0).sum()
```

If this isn't good for you, and you really don't want to generate a mask of booleans and count them (thought I'm not sure why it would bother you), let me know, you can get the same results with loops

Answer (score 0):

You can simply:

```
print(df[df<0].count())
print(df[df==0].count())

a    2
b    1
c    1
d    0
dtype: int64
a    1
b    0
c    1
d    0
dtype: int64
```